# Load alternative source after External JavaScript code failed to load

Tags: feature-request, support

Because the GFW of china ban google service, It is hard to use stackoverflow.
Currently, I am using a chrome extension to replace google js lib.
But today, I meet a big problem - `Human Verification`.
I don't know why stackoverflow see me as a bot.But the bot checker is using `google recaptcha`:

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=en&_=1438579013137 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

which that chrome extension do not contain...so I can not see captcha, can't pass bot checker, can't post a question....
stackoverflow maybe add more `External JavaScript` in future, load alternative source would cover more user, make site more strong.

Above is why I make this feature request.